# Domain Generalization vs Domain Adaptation

Tags: domain-adaptation

What is the difference between domain generalization and domain adaptation?

According to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04373.pdf), domain adaptation deals with unlabelled target domain whereas domain generalization can't do it. What this implies

Answer (score 1):

Didn't read the paper, but I could give you my 2 cents on the question.
I worked quite a bit on the domain adaptation and have experience with it in my own projects.

The concept is actually pretty simple:

**Domain generalization:**
So basically this tells just how well the model generalizes on unseen examples after training. So for example, if I'm predicting dog breeds from the RGBD images the domain generalization measures how well do I predict the images of a certain breed (the breed has been seen during the training), however the images I'm testing domain generalization is disjoint to the training images. Simply you can think of it as test accuracy.

**Domain adaptation:**
Usually, we have a domain **A**, and we have domain **B**. In the example case, we can't really get labelled images of domain **B** (however there's a number of unlabelled images available to us), so we have to train only domain **A**. The simple case relating to the previous example is to imagine you have a simulator that can simulate computer-generated dog images. The simulator creates images in domain A (simulator), which generates artificial examples of dog breeds. Since the dogs are artificially generated by computer software it's not real RGBD pixels and thus they are from a different domain compared to the real dog RGBD images. This way usually Domain Adaptation tries to solve the problem of shifting the learned knowledge of domain **A** to domain **B** in most cases by utilizing a large number of unlabelled images from domain **B**. However, there exist different techniques for example pretty intense data augmentation. Strong Data Augmentation in a way makes a model that is robust to many different domains at the same time that's why it sometimes works well in Domain Adaptation from domain A to domain B.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time!  For Domain generalization in testing images are disjoint with training images but will the breeds be the same? If so any deep learning model used for classification does domain generalization?

Comment: yes, that's the case. There's an assumption that the domain generalization generalizes well on unseen examples.